# Creating a hash in Perl

Tags: perl, hash

How do I create a hash in Perl which uses the directory name as the key, and then stores both the count of files in the directory as well as the names each of the files? Is it possible using hash of hashes or hash of arrays?

I would appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this seems to do the trick (the printing of the hash using Dumper() at the end is just to show you what the hashref contains):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $dir = $ENV{PWD};
opendir( DIR, $dir ) or die $!;
my @files = grep { -f "$dir/$_" } readdir( DIR );
my $hash = {
    $dir => {
        count => scalar( @files ),
        files => \@files,
    }
};

print Dumper( $hash ), "\n";
```

Comment: What about this approach? I am very new to Perl when it comes to hashes.

    while (my $line = <SRCINC>) {
       my($filename, $dir) = fileparse($line);
       $data_{$dir}{file}=$filename;
       $data_{$dir}{count}++;
    }

Comment: Instead of gluing paths yourself, use File::Spec (or something built on it).

Answer (score 4):

Hash values must be scalars, so the real question is how to get two values into one scalar. References are scalars, so a reference to a hash would work.

```
$data{$dir} = {
   file_count => 0+@files,
   files      => \@files,
};
```

Note that the file count is redundant. `0+@{ $data{$dir}{files} }` could be used for the file count. If you choose to get rid of this redundancy, you could use

```
$files{$dir} = \@files;
```

The file count is available as

```
0+@{ $files{$dir} }
```

and the files are available as

```
@{ $files{$dir} }
```

(The `0+` can be omitted in scalar context.)

Comment: In my humble opinion, `scalar @files` will be more readable than `0+@files`.

Comment: @Alan Haggai Alavi, You're the first I've heard say that, and many have told me the opposite. Most think the numification operator (`0+`) is much clearer since it indicates a number will be returned. I pity the person who thinks addition works on lists.

Comment: @Alan Haggai Alavi, `"".` is a stringification operator, `0+` is a numification operator, and `!!` is a booleanisation operator. There are times where you have to use one of these and not `scalar`, and those times are more numerous than the times you can't use those and must use `scalar`, so I suggest you get used to them. You appear to be confusing lack of readability with lack of familiarity.

Comment: `"".`, `0+`, `!!` aren't discrete operators at all; they're glued-together operators and operands performing implicit coercions. In this particular case, how about `int @files` as both indicative and line-noiseless?

Comment: @Richard Simões, `int` does more than numify. Same argument applies as `scalar`: I see no reason to use `scalar` or `int` here and `0+` elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Personally almost always I use hash references instead perl hashes (and arrayrefs instead perl arrays, too). Example:

```
my $dirs = {
     '/home/user' => [ '.profile', '.bashrc', 'My_pic.png' ],
     '/root'      => [ '.profile', '.zshrc' ]
};
```

`my $var = { (...) }` makes hash reference, `=>` is just a synonym of comma `,` but allows distinguishing between hash keys and values. `[ (...) ]` makes annonymous array reference which is assigned as hash value.

You don't have to store redundant information like number of files, you can just evaluate array in scalar context:

```
my $root_files = $dirs->{'/root'};
$size = scalar @{$root_files};
```

You can [read more about hashes here](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~abatko/computers/programming/perl/howto/hash/#clear__or_empty__a_hash_reference) and [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).